# Laravel loads all relationships for a specific resource

Tags: php, laravel

I have below model, with the `fields` relationship defined.

```php
//Stream.php
    /**
     * A stream can have many fields
     *
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Field::class);
    }
```

In my database, I have two streams:

```
//table: streams
id | name
1  | doc_stream
2  | email_stream
```

And 4 fields:

```
//table: fields
id | stream_id | name
1  | 1         | Field #1
2  | 1         | Field #2
3  | 1         | Field #3
4  | 2         | Field #4
```

So by this setup, I thought I could simply do:

```php
//streams/1/fields/1
public function show(Stream $stream, Field $field)
{
   dd($stream->with('fields')->get());
}
```

Which would then return all the fields, only for the `$stream.id = 1`.

However, the relationship loads **all** streams:

[image]

Am I not able to load a relationship only for the specific resource I am showing?

Comment: The column name isn't `field` right? Laravel searches for column names, so it should probably be `name` where you have written `field`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? What column name?

Comment: dd($stream->with('fields')->get('1'));

Comment: But adding `1` does not make it dynamic? I am using route model binding to get the `stream`, and thus would like to return all associated `fields` for only that specific stream.

Comment: I don't think you need to load again the fields, you can use simply : `dd($stream->fields);`

Comment: What you have in your `$stream` and `$field`? Did you get `id` or whole model? @oliverbj

Comment: @mare96: The url is: `streams/1/fields/1`

Comment: In addition, $stream is already the model found by the route, since you use `->get()`, it's now use the Eloquent Model. Your result is normal, you get all Stream models. Only use the dynamic property `$stream->fields` to access your fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) to resolve the `$field`. And using `$stream->with('fields')->get();` to load the relationship.

It is all working as intended, I think there is a misunderstanding here on how the route model binding and relationships work.

```php
$stream->with('fields')->get();
```

This will load all streams since it starts a new query and is the same as doing `Stream::with('fields')->get()`.

If you want a specific field for your stream you can do:

```php
$field = $stream->fields()->findOrFail($fieldId);
```

In you controller method that would look something like this

```php
// streams/1/fields/1
public function show(Stream $stream, $fieldId)
{
   // findOrFail will throw a 404 if the field could not be found for the specific stream
   $field = $stream->fields()->findOrFail($fieldId);

   dd($field);
}
```

`$stream` with id `1` (for your example url) will have been resolved by the route model binding.

Otherwise this probably already works if you have setup the correct route model binding:

```php
// streams/1/fields/1
public function show(Stream $stream, Field $field)
{
   dd($field);
}
```

However this will also load a field for another stream (the field does not belong to) since it doesn't know how to scope the query for the stream with the id `1`.

Comment: Ah, I see! I must've misunderstood how the `with` was working together with route model binding. But what if I simply pass `$stream->load('fields');`? Insted of using the `get()`?

Comment: `$stream->load('fields');` does the same as you would access `$stream->fields` and loads the full relationship (internally runs something like `$stream->fields = $stream->fields()->get();`.

Comment: But that only returns the fields for the specific field I am accessing (which is what I want - all fields for the specific stream)

Comment: Did you see my comment ? only use `$stream->fields` and read the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @VincentDecaux Yes, but I will need to be able to access the stream properties as well. With `$stream->fields` only returns the fields, not the `stream` object as well.

Comment: @AlexBouma 's answer is good. But you need to provide what do you need. Your `stream` object is `$stream`, lol.

Comment: You have the `$stream` already and can access fields on that like `$stream->name` and access all fields bu doing `$stream->fields` or access the field from the route by doing `$field->name`. I think we might be missing what you really want to do or access.

Comment: @oliverbj you understand fields is a property of stream ? you can access for example `$stream->name` and all fields by `$stream->fields`. If you want the details of fields, you just loop on the property

Comment: I also misread `$stream->with('fields')->get()` and thought this would get all fields for the stream but this simply loads all streams since it starts a new query and does the same as doing `Stream::with('fields')->get()`. Updated answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I think streame table should have an attribut field_id and you should edit the function like below:

```
public function fields()
 {
    return $this->hasMany(Field::class, 'field_id', 'id');
 }
```